# Throwing error when RecyclerView is added to xml layout file in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an Android Application. I am trying to use RecyclerView in my application. So I added the RecyclerXml to my layout file. But when I run my app, it is throwing error.

This is my main_activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/main_activity_parallax_initial_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/htab_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/apple"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="HELLO"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/main_activity_toolbar_height"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />
          <!--  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />-->
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/default_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then I set the content of the default_content_container with a fragment.

This is the xml of fragment with recycler view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dc_rv_destination"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> </LinearLayout>
```

I did not initialize anything and I do nothing in fragment.

But when I run, it is giving me this error.

```
05-28 14:42:15.956 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-28 14:42:15.956 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
05-28 14:42:15.956 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
05-28 14:42:15.960 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
05-28 14:42:15.960 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
05-28 14:42:15.964 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-28 14:42:15.964 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bc9648)
05-28 14:42:15.964 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=25349, eventTime=1585081, downTime=277306, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
05-28 14:42:15.964 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=25350, eventTime=1585450, downTime=277306, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1654)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:11596)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13950)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3097)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3086)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2923)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3086)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2923)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3086)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1077)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2923)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3086)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2923)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13947)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3086)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2923)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3086)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2923)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3086)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2923)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3086)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2923)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13947)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2224)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1411)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2239)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1872)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 14:42:15.968 8654-8654/com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent E/AndroidRuntime:    at java.la
```

So why can I not add recycler view? When I add list view instead, I can run app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens exactly because you "did not initialize anything and I do nothing in fragment."

RecyclerView **MUST BE** initialised view a LayoutManager immediately after being inflated.

That happens because a lot of layout calculation for RecycleView happens in the LayoutManager.

That said, simple fix, after inflating the fragment layout, during the fragment `onCreateView` add the layout manager to it via:

```
recycler.setLayoutManager( /* add here your layout manager of choice */ );
```